# How to retrieve cookies on a https connection?

Tags: java, cookies, https, jsoup

I'm trying to save the cookies in a URL that uses SSL but always return NULL.

```
private Map<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<String, String>();

    private Document get(String url) throws IOException {
            Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url);
            for (Entry<String, String> cookie : cookies.entrySet()) {
                connection.cookie(cookie.getKey(), cookie.getValue());
            }
            Response response = connection.execute();
            cookies.putAll(response.cookies());
            return response.parse();
        }

    private void buscaJuizado(List<Movimentacao> movimentacoes) {
            try {
                Connection.Response res = Jsoup                          .connect("https://projudi.tjpi.jus.br/projudi/publico/buscas/ProcessosParte?publico=true")
  .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20120716 Firefox/15.0a2")
  .timeout(0)
  .response();
  cookies = res.cookies();
  Document doc = get("https://projudi.tjpi.jus.br/projudi/listagens/DadosProcesso?  numeroProcesso=" + campo);
  System.out.println(doc.body());
  } catch (IOException ex) {
     Logger.getLogger(ConsultaProcessoTJPi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
}
```

I try to capture the cookies the first connection, but always they are always set to NULL. I think it might be some Cois because of the secure connection (HTTPS)
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not HTTPS. The problem is more or less a small mistake.

To fix your issue you can simply replace `.response()` with `.execute()`. Like so,

```
private void buscaJuizado(List<Movimentacao> movimentacoes) {
  try {
    Connection.Response res = Jsoup
      .connect("https://projudi.tjpi.jus.br/projudi/publico/buscas/ProcessosParte?publico=true")
      .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:15.0) Gecko/20120716 Firefox/15.0a2")
      .timeout(0)
      .execute(); // changed fron response()
    cookies = res.cookies(); 
    Document doc = get("https://projudi.tjpi.jus.br/projudi/listagens/DadosProcesso?numeroProcesso="+campo);
    System.out.println(doc.body());
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ConsultaProcessoTJPi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
}
```

Overall you have to make sure you execute the request first.
Calling `.response()` is useful to grab the `Connection.Response` object *after* the request has already been executed.  Obviously the `Connection.Response` object won't be very useful if you haven't executed the request.

In fact if you were to try calling `res.body()` on the unexecuted response you would receive the following exception indicating the issue.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Request must be executed (with .execute(), .get(), or .post() before getting response body